# Windows 10 laptop doesn't close all the windows when I perform shutdown from the start menu - Is it normal?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

Two days ago, I got a new Acer Windows 10 laptop. I noticed often that when I shut it down or restart (there's no option for hibernating) using the start menu from the left bottom, the windows that were kept open before the time of shutting down or restarting, were kept open after I turned the laptop on, or restarted it. I don't think this is normal, is it? I did notice that the light turned off each time I shut down the laptop, so that's what's expected.

If no, then what could be the underlying problem, and how could I fix it myself?

Comment: Are you sure that you shutdown it? everything looks like it was hibernated...

Comment: @Akina thanks for your comment! So I went to the start menu, and the power button on the screen from the start menu (I'm not talking about the physical power button on the top right of the keyboard) has three options, sleep, shutdown or restart. There's no hibernate option at all.

Comment: Check if hidden file `c:\hiberfil.sys` exists? if so then hibernation is enabled. It is enabled by default, and "show hibernate option in start-shutdows" menu option is disabled by default.

Comment: Programs can register to be restarted. Please list all programs you observed this behavior with.

Comment: The hibernate option is available in the settings under the startup submenu.

Comment: Also is it that you have a problem where you don’t want the applications to reopen after shutdown/restart, right?

Comment: Also do the applications that open after shutdown/restart were opened from where you left them or on the startup page?

Comment: @Valay_17 I don't see any hibernate option on the power button that pops up from the start up menu.

I'm not sure I understand your first question, sorry.

For your second question, here's what just happened: I restarted the laptop with some update (so basically chose the "update and restart" option). After restarting, initially, for a second or two, there were no open chrome browser pages that were kept intentionally open at the time of restart. However, after a second or two, they popped up and filled up my screen.

Comment: What I mean is : You don’t want the applications to start on their own right?

Comment: Just restarted it again, this time with no update options, but I see after restarting that the chrome browser pages are there to begin with.

Comment: @Valay_17 Oh I see, thanks. It's better if they don't start on their own. But my question is more of a concern: if they do start on their own where I left them off before shutdown or restart, does it necessarily mean something is wrong?

Comment: Nope,it’s alright as some of them have options were they turn on automatically after startup

Comment: @Valay_17 Oh okay, then I've no concern :) Thanks then!

Comment: You can turn them off as well,just go to settings and search for it.

Comment: Okay will do so, will search in settings!

Comment: @Valay_17 You're right, my bad.. I've deleted that comment to prevent mis-information